# Finding the length of the shortest subsequence that needs to be replaced in order to have all the characters equally represented?

Tags: perl

I have a file composed of 800 letters in a row and in uneven numbers. I have to have it so the 20 letters are equally divided into 40 letters each. I have to find the shortest subsequence that contains all the characters that need to be replaced. That means same numbers of "A", "C", "D" and so on.
The sequence is this:

> ASQLDRFRVFLGWDNGMMLVYQGNKTYEPWLNCDMASPTLSLVSKKAPKILKAADINTTLQPCLAFFIELLLKGIDNERIPNSGSGGREMGLLAPTYSSEATLVTRENNMMEGVHGFENMQDVEVIKLKLPEGYSDVCHFMFMLAGILYIVYDLQMHMSSERETGKFPNPLSDEEFDNPKVVVTNSFVLLEFTVTGAGARPSEQGQEPHNLGATKGSLAISSKTPEIHKDTNPASAQFEGKHTESDAKGVSNEDVFITKERDGREVEPTIKLSKKSVLNPMNVVYNPMLQISEGALRKHSMNDEITILNNTLINKERSVDLGAVSFVNDLLIDKLGCVSGKLAVQLNQSAPPEILHGKDPLTLFLGNTIALMLSKMQRIRVWEEYIFLNLHLALAWEPLLGNLKTHDSQKKWALCGFLIISRIRNLFESEGPVHGLRFSAMPCNTDTRQIKALERFPYAPEKPQWHGDELESPCRLVVASKLLASHDGVSIGKTIGSWPLPAQRYNAYVAWAANDSSILSARPGFAVKEDRLGHSLAQESGTIVVRNPQYGVRFINYNKDEHREFKREATFYPKTVVTHLGAIEGTLMFEIGDAAFTMLHLEEATDAEVRELYYMDMLDKKSSLGRACERIRRVLAPGDHKANGLESAIVSGQNGYEGRIRGLQTFQSNPLKKGRTHMAFCTTLHPFGGLKLVSSQLLKKELAVGTYGHQRTVLHSAEYSCPTSIPNLEGLMYNLISAQGEVNSDAKCHYAALAYICLQVRSVSMNQTEASDLRNFLETPILANDALASEQLLGSKKAKS

I've tried running expressions but I don't understand what expression would help in this case when I look through my notes.

```
$file ="Nuritasprotein.txt";
open IN, $file, or die "Cant open $file. $. \n";
while(<IN>){
    chomp;
    $file = $nuritasprotein;
    @Nuritas =split(//,$_); #To get each leter to be an item in the array
    foreach$letter(@Nuritas) {
        $count{$letter}++; #Counts how many of each character is in the sequence(array)
    }
}

close(IN);

foreach $key  (sort  (keys %count)){
    print "$key: $count{$key}\n";#Prints the number of each letters apperance
 }
```

This code lets me know how many of each letter there are but I dont know where to go from there to find the shortest subsequence. Any help would be appreciated on how to tackle this using perl.
The result should say how many characters need to be replaced to have an even amount of each letter.

Comment: *"I have to have it so the 20 letters are equally divided into 40 letters each."* What 20 letters are you referring to?

Comment: The 20 letters inside the string, there is an uneven amount in the original file so I have to find and replace the shortest subsequence that will give me 40 of each letter

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to do, the letters A, B, C, .., T gives 20 characters, but the string you show contains for instance the letter V.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland - this is a biology project. There are 20 different letters in the input (missing B,J,O,U,X,Z) representing [the twenty amino acids](http://www.cryst.bbk.ac.uk/education/AminoAcid/the_twenty.html).

Comment: Yes I see that there is a V, there are only 20 characters of the alphabet inside this sequence, I believe J is one of the ones missing too. There’s 20/26 off the alphabet in the sequence.

Comment: *"I have to have it so the 20 letters are equally divided into 40 letters each"* Could you clarify what this means with an example?

Comment: So I’ve a 100 letters in a sequence there are 20 specific letters in the sequence some letters like A V & T appear let’s say 10 times each, I need it to have it so they only appear 5 times each if that make it understandable

Comment: So we have a string with a restricted alphabet, into which some substitutions have been made from the same alphabet, making the distribution of the letters no longer uniform(e.g., too many A's, not enough H's). Are you saying you need to find the shortest string containing all the letters that are not uniformly distributed, and then propose an alteration that would make the distribution uniform again?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I have to do

Comment: Okay, my answer finds that string and then does my best guess at fixing the distribution. Please comment on that answer if it's not what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is my best guess at what you're actually asking for. I'm working my way backward from a good string to a bad one, assuming I understood your criteria for "bad". [Edit: I didn't fix the distribution! Added the block of code that does it.]

Let's start with a 40-character string with the right distribution of A-E (so there are 8 of each).

```
AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEE
```

Now let's randomize the order.

```
DEAADCEBEEADBBEABBBCCECADCDDECCEBCAADBDA
```

Now let's mess up the distribution. When we do this, we increase the count of letters of one kind and, because we're substituting, we decrease the count of the letter we replaced. So let's walk through the string and change every fifth letter to something else.

```
DEAAACEBEAADBBAABBBBCECAACDDEECEBCDADBDC
....D....E....E....C....D....C....A....A
             ^
```

We've done the following:

- Added an A, removed a D (+1 A, -1 D)
- Added an A, removed an E (+2 A, -1 D, -1 E)
- Added another A, removed another E (+3 A, -1 D, -2 E)
- Added a B, removed a C (+3 A, +1 B, -1 C, -1 D, -2 E)
- Added an A, removed a D (+4 A, +1 B, -1 C, -2 D, -2 E)
- Added an E, removed a C (+4 A, +1 B, -2 C, -2 D, -1 E)
- Added a D, removed an A (+3 A, +1 B, -2 C, -1 D, -1 E)
- Added a C, removed an A  (+2 A, +1 B, -1 C, -1 D, -1 E)

The count of changes still sums to 0, since for each letter we added, we took away another. (This should be the case for the 800-character string as well; we're just looking for a count of 40 for each of the 20 characters for a "correct" string in that case.)

What we want to do now is take the altered string and find the smallest substring into which we can remove 2 A's and 1 B, and add 1 C, D, and E. An example string that would work would therefore be AAB (or any permutation of that).This substring could then be altered by using the initial frequency counts to add back the characters we're missing to fix the distribution.

The caret in the text above shows the shortest substring we could make the change in (BAA -> CDE) to balance the distribution again. (Note that AACEB would meet the distribution criterion, as it has 2 A's and one B, but it is longer than BAA, so it's not the solution).

What we want to do, then, is search through the string, ticking off characters in the set of "ones we need to remove" until we find a substring that contains all of them, since ordering does not matter. We want to start at the first character, and then scan repeatedly through the string, looking for substrings that meet the "too many" criterion, retaining the shortest one as the winner.

Because we have to *count* character occurrences, trying to do this with regexes would be very inefficient, especially in cases where the distribution is such that we end up doing a lot of backtracking. The easiest way to do this is to set up a hash containing the characters we have too many of, and then iterate over the string, reducing the count of excess characters as we see them, and deleting the character from consideration when we've used it up. Once we have nothing left to take away, the string we have meets the criterion of "smallest string containing all the 'off' character counts". We then repeat this in overlapping scans of the original string, looking for the shortest possible option.

Fixing the distribution entails walking through your minimum string, and replacing the excess characters with the ones we're missing. We reduce the counts of both and drop characters from consideration when they reach zero, just like before.

Finally, we repeat the character counting exercise from the start of the program, and verify that we have exactly 40 or each character now in the complete string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(reduce);

$|++;

# Bucket all the characters
my $string = <DATA>;
chomp $string;

my %buckets;

for (split //,$string) {
  $buckets{$_}++;
}

for (keys %buckets) {
  if ($buckets{$_} <= 40){
    delete $buckets{$_}
  } else {
    $buckets{$_} = $buckets{$_} - 40;
  }
}
die "no exceptions to the 40 rule" unless keys %buckets;
print "Exceptional characters: ", keys %buckets, "\n";
my $excess_count = reduce {$a + $b} values %buckets;
print "Excess letter count: $excess_count\n";

my $scan_base = 0;
my @chars = split //, $string;
my ($minimal, $capture_start, $capture_end) = ('', -1, -1);
for (my $i = 0; $i < length($string)-$excess_count; $i++) {
  my %discards = %buckets;
  my $j;
  my $reset;
  for ($j = $i; $j < length($string)-$excess_count; $j++) {
    if (exists $discards{$chars[$j]}) {
      # Still have some of these in excess.
      $reset = $j unless $reset;
      $discards{$chars[$j]}--;
      # no more left of this character, stop looking for it
      if ($discards{$chars[$j]} == 0) {
        # We've met the "all of the excess chars are in here" criterion.
        delete $discards{$chars[$j]};
      }
      # drop out if we've deleted all the keys.
      last unless keys %discards;
    }
  }
  # give up if we couldn't discard all the characters we needed to.
  last if reduce{$a + $b} values %discards;
  # We consumed all the excess characters, so @chars[$i..$j] is a potential
  # substring. We'll go around again, one character further on, to see if we
  # can find a shorter match.
  my $possible = join '', @chars[$i..$j];
  if (length($minimal) == 0 or length($possible) < length($minimal)) {
    print "updating minimal to $possible (@{[length $possible]})\n";
    $minimal = $possible;
  }
  $i = $reset;
}
# Fix the distribution. We know what we have too much of and too little of
# from the initial scan of the string, so we'll simply iterate through the
# found string, replacing the excess with the insufficient until we're done.
for my $loc ($capture_start..$capture_end) {
  if ($excess{$chars[$loc]}) {
    my $fix = (keys %lacking)[int rand(scalar keys %lacking)];
    $excess{$chars[$loc]}--;
    $lacking{$fix}--;
    delete $excess{$chars[$loc]} unless $excess{$chars[$loc]};
    delete $lacking{$fix}        unless $lacking{$fix};
    $chars[$loc] = $fix;
  }
}

# Rebucket to validate.
my %verify;
for (@chars) {
  $verify{$_}++;
}
my %invert = reverse(%verify);
die "didn't fix: @[{keys %invert}]" unless keys %invert == 1 and (keys %invert)[0] == 40;
print "\n";
print join '',@chars,"\n";
__DATA__
ASQLDRFRVFLGWDNGMMLVYQGNKTYEPWLNCDMASPTLSLVSKKAPKILKAADINTTLQPCLAFFIELLLKGIDNERIPNSGSGGREMGLLAPTYSSEATLVTRENNMMEGVHGFENMQDVEVIKLKLPEGYSDVCHFMFMLAGILYIVYDLQMHMSSERETGKFPNPLSDEEFDNPKVVVTNSFVLLEFTVTGAGARPSEQGQEPHNLGATKGSLAISSKTPEIHKDTNPASAQFEGKHTESDAKGVSNEDVFITKERDGREVEPTIKLSKKSVLNPMNVVYNPMLQISEGALRKHSMNDEITILNNTLINKERSVDLGAVSFVNDLLIDKLGCVSGKLAVQLNQSAPPEILHGKDPLTLFLGNTIALMLSKMQRIRVWEEYIFLNLHLALAWEPLLGNLKTHDSQKKWALCGFLIISRIRNLFESEGPVHGLRFSAMPCNTDTRQIKALERFPYAPEKPQWHGDELESPCRLVVASKLLASHDGVSIGKTIGSWPLPAQRYNAYVAWAANDSSILSARPGFAVKEDRLGHSLAQESGTIVVRNPQYGVRFINYNKDEHREFKREATFYPKTVVTHLGAIEGTLMFEIGDAAFTMLHLEEATDAEVRELYYMDMLDKKSSLGRACERIRRVLAPGDHKANGLESAIVSGQNGYEGRIRGLQTFQSNPLKKGRTHMAFCTTLHPFGGLKLVSSQLLKKELAVGTYGHQRTVLHSAEYSCPTSIPNLEGLMYNLISAQGEVNSDAKCHYAALAYICLQVRSVSMNQTEASDLRNFLETPILANDALASEQLLGSKKAKS
```

This gives the solution

> QLDRFRVFLGWDNGMMLVYQGNKTYEPWLNCDMASPTLSLVSKKAPKILKAADINTTLQPCLAFFIELLLKGIDNERIPNSGSGGREMGLLAPTYSSEATLVTRENNMMEGVHGFENMQDVEVIKLKLPEGYSDVCHFMFMLAGILYIVYDLQMHMSSERETGKFPNPLSDEEFDNPKVVVTNSFVLLEFTVTGAGARPSEQGQEPHNLGATKGSLAISSKTPEIHKDTNPASAQFEGKHTESDAKGVSNEDVFITKERDGREVEPTIKLSKKSVLNPMNVVYNPMLQISEGALRKHSMNDEITILNNTLINKERSVDLGAVSFVNDLLIDKLGCVSGKLAVQLNQSAPPEILHGKDPLTLFLGNTIALMLSKMQRIRVWEEYIFLNLHLALAWEPLLGNLKTHDSQKKWALCGFL
>   (416 characters).
>
> ASQPDRFRYFQFWDIQMMMDYQYPMFYDPWDYCDMWFPTQWQCDCQYPRIWCQQDINTTQQPCFDFFIDHMRMMIDNCRIPNHCRYQRWMHHFMPTYHYQMTMCTRFNNMMFFQHMFHNMQDYWVIYHWFPMQYMDVCHFMFMHWFIQYIVYDWQMHMWCCRWTYKFPNPMYDCWFDNPKVVVTNYFVMHWFTVTWMMYRPHMQHQCPHNCCWTKGWYYICYKTPYIHKDTNPYYWQFEGKHTEWDWKGVCNEDVFITKERDGREVEPTIKWHKKWVCNPMNVVYNPMHQISEGWWRKHSMNDEITICNNTWINKERSVDCGCVSFVNDWCIDKCGCVSGKCHVQWNQSCPPEIHHGKDPCTHFWGNTICCMCSKMQRIRVWEEYIFCNHHWAWAWEPCWGNWKTHDSQKKWAWCGFWIISRIRNLFESEGPVHGLRFSAMPCNTDTRQIKALERFPYAPEKPQWHGDELESPCRLVVASKLLASHDGVSIGKTIGSWPLPAQRYNAYVAWAANDSSILSARPGFAVKEDRLGHSLAQESGTIVVRNPQYGVRFINYNKDEHREFKREATFYPKTVVTHLGAIEGTLMFEIGDAAFTMLHLEEATDAEVRELYYMDMLDKKSSLGRACERIRRVLAPGDHKANGLESAIVSGQNGYEGRIRGLQTFQSNPLKKGRTHMAFCTTLHPFGGLKLVSSQLLKKELAVGTYGHQRTVLHSAEYSCPTSIPNLEGLMYNLISAQGEVNSDAKCHYAALAYICLQVRSVSMNQTEASDLRNFLETPILANDALASEQLLGSKKAKS